# PHP Limit in POST variables

Tags: php, post, encoding, base64

I'm trying to send an array to a PHP script via POST method. First I **serialize()** it, then used **base64_encode()** on it. After receving it, the script then **base64_decode()** it then **unserialize()** it. I know that using base64_encode functions increases the data size by 33%, so I'm worried that the POST variables might be overwhelmed, and thus giving me an error. Is there a limit to a string that can be POST'ed? Or better, is there another way that I can use other than base64_encode to correctly pass the array to the other script? By the way, without using base64_ functions on serialization, I get the "Error:.. offset" notice.

Comment: Is this from a form? How large do you expect your data to be? Any reason not to store this internally, e.g. in a file that is identified by a session ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on the contents of the array. If it is mostly text, then you could compress/decompress using gzcompress/gzuncompress the resulting serialized object:

```
$encoded = base64_encode(gzcompress(serialize($original)));

$original = unserialize(gzuncompress(base64_decode($_POST['encoded'])));
```

gzencode/gzdecode will probably give better compression for larger size data. If your aray contains binary data, or even worse compressed data, then this technique will probably not gain much if anything.

In addition to the PHP configuration already mentioned, your web server can also impose POST size limits, for instance the LimitRequestBody directive in apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Comment: Hmmm... I'll be passing Doubles so maybe I can use gz_ functions, can't I?

Comment: I've done some tests with arrays of 100, 10,000 and 1,000,000 random doubles. In all cases they compress to less than 50% of the original size using gzcompress (about 48%, 42% and 41% respectively).

Answer (score 5):

A php.ini value ir responsible for POST max size:

```
post_max_size = 10M
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to worry about size, But I'd consider using [sessions](http://php.net/session) for this purpose

Comment: Dunno about sessions, how about a database?

Comment: @Briedis if you're gonna save that data in the database anyway - then save it. But if it's temporary data, then sessions is your choice. By the way, adding certain example and user case to your question, you are dramatically increase answers quality

Answer (score 0):

1) The maximum amount of data you can POST is post_max_size directive in php.ini. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

2) Perhaps you can do it through $_SESSION?