# PHP Limit in POST variables

Tags: php, post, encoding, base64

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Limit in POST variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064485/php-limit-in-post-variables)

Hi! I'm trying to send an array to a PHP script via POST method. First I **serialize()** it, then used **base64_encode()** on it. After receving it, the script then **base64_decode()** it then **unserialize()** it. I know that using base64_encode functions increases the data size by 33%, so I'm worried that the POST variables might be overwhelmed, and thus giving me an error. Is there a limit to a string that can be POST'ed? Or better, is there another way that I can use other than base64_encode to correctly pass the array to the other script? By the way, without using base64_ functions on serialization, I get the "Error:.. offset" notice.

Edit:

This is the serialization:

```
$serial_coords = base64_encode(serialize($coords_arr));
```

This is the unserialization

```
$coords_array = unserialize(base64_decode($_POST['serial-coords']));
```

Comment: Is this from a form? How large do you expect your data to be? Any reason not to store this internally, e.g. in a file that is identified by a session ID?

Comment: it's very impolite to ask the same question twice [PHP Limit in POST variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064485/php-limit-in-post-variables)

Comment: wtf? Please don't ask duplicates. -1 and voting to close

Comment: agreed on duplicate matters :) -1

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. I didn't know how the duplication happened. :(

Answer (score 1):

1) The maximum amount of data you can POST is post_max_size directive in php.ini. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

2) Perhaps you can do it through $_SESSION?