# PHP ignores posted data

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to post an image to a php page as a base64 encoded string and it works fine while the image file is smaller than about 800KB but if the file is bigger the $_POST var is missing the image value.

post data looks like

```
email=xyz@xyz.com&image={image base64 encoded}&name=Bob
```

if I inspect the $_POST var using var_dump($_POST) and the file is smaller than 800KB it prints the following:

```
array(3) {
    ["email"]=>string(11) "xyz@xyz.com"
    ["image"]=>string(936816) "{image base64 encoded}"
    ["name"]=>string(3) "Bob"
}
```

...if the file is bigger than about 800KB it prints:

```
array(2) {
    ["email"]=>string(11) "xyz@xyz.com"
    ["name"]=>string(3) "Bob"
}
```

But in both cases the data is definitely posted to the php script (I inspected the webrequests through fiddler).

post_max_size is set to 8MB and memory_limit to 128MB so this should not be a problem.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: What's your form's tag code?

Comment: I'm not using a form i'm posting the data through a WebRequest from c# but as said in my post, if i inspect the request using fiddler it's correct, so this should not cause the problem!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP some $\_POST values missing but are present in php://input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077969/php-some-post-values-missing-but-are-present-in-php-input)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that it has something to do with server limitations... although POST data has no limits, sometimes (most of the time) there are some outgoing/incoming server/script limitation.
Could you try to gzip binary content ant try to push it through POST?

```
$encoded = base64_encode(gzcompress(serialize($original)));

$original = unserialize(gzuncompress(base64_decode($_POST['encoded'])));
```

[Idea Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064485/php-limit-in-post-variables)